# Is it possible to set width of global actions list

Tags: css, global-actions, home-page-layout

we would like to widen the list that contains global actions. As you can see, we have an action that has a longer name than the element. We are planning also to add several other. Is it possible to make this list wider (using css somewhere or some setting)? Or the only way to contain the whole name of action is to make it shorter?

[image: Global actions list]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no you cannot increase/change width of global actions list icon wider as this is salesforce standard inbuild functionality and would recommend to post Idea [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/post) so that it can reviewed. However you can customize quick action icons using static resource.

Thanks